# reading file into an array but only the last file is stored?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am reading from a file and storing them into an array....

```
         f = new File("some file");
        try {
            s = new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String theWord [] = new String[100];.
        while(s.hasNext()){

            int i=0;

            theWord[i]=s.next();
            //print
            System.out.println(theWord[i]);

            i++;     
        }
        System.out.println(theWord[0]);
        System.out.println(theWord[1]);
```

Say the file has the words: Hello Programmer.
The output is:

```
    Hello
    programmer
    programmer
    null
```

THe last two lines are puzzling me. It shows that the 0 index of theWord is programmer and 1 index is null when just before the zero index should be hello and the 1 index should be programmer.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move:

```
 int i=0;
```

Outside the loop. You always update `theWord[0]` value.

Comment: also, Check out Sting.split() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

You are re-initializing `i` to `0` in your `while` loop, so every time, the 0<sup>th</sup> element of your array is overwritten.

```
while(s.hasNext()){
    int i=0;  // Move this outside the while loop
```